# Manhwa about a girl who is sucked into a book where the second male lead died of sadness

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I read a manhwa about a year or two ago.

It was about a girl who was reading a book where the second male lead died of sadness (I'm not sure about this part) because he wasn't the soulmate of female lead; they have soulmates in the manhwa and you're supposed to have the same mark as someone somewhere on your body. Well anyway, the girl get sucked in into the book and realizes she is the female lead's younger sister and makes it her job to not make second male lead sad anymore. It takes time, but she finally gets into his heart and because she already loved him, it didn't take that long for them to be together.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead and the second male lead?

Comment: If anyone posts a correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons near the top-left corner of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.

Answer (score 3):

Is this ***[The Villain's Savior](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/om0gcwm/the-villain-s-savior)***...?

> Set on a path to tragedy and misfortune from a young age, Aseph Randell is doomed to die a villain. That is, until the mysterious Elzay Tiathe appears in his life with a promise: "I can save you." After having vivid visions of him for so long, can Elzay untangle the twisted fate tied to Aseph...or will they both be dragged down together?

A woman reads a novel titled "The Crest of God," set in a world in which matching pairs of crests magically appear on people's bodies to indicate who their soulmate is.

The woman becomes particularly attached to the villain of the novel, Azef Randall, who endured abuse and misfortune from a young age, fell in love with the heroine of the novel, Elisa Thyase (whose crest he did not share), and ultimately died heartbroken at the blade of her soulmate, Alchester.

So attached does this woman become to Azef that she has dreams about him while reading the novel, and cries herself to sleep after reading of his death, yearning for the ability to save him.

She then wakes up within the world of the novel as the twin sister of Elisa, Elljae Thyase -- a character who didn't exist in the original novel -- and sets about trying to change Azef's fate. Based on what I've read, the story appears to be a romance between the two of them going forward.

[image] [image]